# Finding the range of function - square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

find the range of y = $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{5-x}$

Since domain of square root function is defined for $f(x) \geq 0$ therefore : $\sqrt{x-1} \geq 0  ; x \geq 1 $ also $\sqrt{5-x } \geq 0 ;\: x \leq 5$

therefore domain of the function is $x \in [1,5]$

Please guide how to find range of this function

Comment: @Brian and sultan: Sorry about the "misfire": I didn't read the question carefully (I thought I read $\sqrt{x - 5}$!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Note that

$$f(x)^2=(x-1)+2\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}+(5-x)=4+2\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}\;.$$

Clearly $2\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}\ge 0$ for all $x\in[1,5]$, so $4$ is the minimum value of $f(x)^2$, and $2=f(1)=f(5)$ is the minimum value of $f(x)$. To find the maximum value, you must find the maximum value of $(x-1)(5-x)$. The graph of $y=(x-1)(5-x)$ is a parabola opening down; where is its vertex?

Answer (score 2):

You have the domain correct; how does $y$ behave within this domain?  Make a table of values, or plot it.

$$y(1) = y(5) = 2$$

$$y(3) = 2 \sqrt{2}$$

By symmetry, the min of the range is at the endpoints, while the max is in the center.  Thus, the range is $y \in [2, 2 \sqrt{2}]$.